# Java Thread object manipulation reflected, how?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the below code.

```
public class Test implements Runnable
{
    static int id = 0;
    int value = 0;
    public static int getId() {
        return ++id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t = new Test();

        t.value = 10;
        new Thread(t, "child " + getId()).start();
        new Thread(t, "child " + getId()).start();
        t.value = 20;
        new Thread(t, "child " + getId()).start();
        new Thread(t, "child " + getId()).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Thread " +  Thread.currentThread().getName() + " started");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Data - " + this.value);
    }
}
```

Output on sample run:

```
Thread child 1 started
Thread child 2 started
child 2 Data - 20
child 1 Data - 20
Thread child 3 started
child 3 Data - 20
Thread child 4 started
child 4 Data - 20
```

I could see the thread object's (Test) latest data is reflected in all the threads. But how?

I am expecting that the threads started and executed before line `t.value=20` should have the data value '10'. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
 new Thread(t, "child " + getId()).start();,
```

does not mean, that new Thread is started at this moment. It may take some time until its started.
If you want to wait for it, you can extract it to a variable.

```
Thread t=new Thread(t, "child " + getId()); 
t.start();
```

and wait for it to finish: `t.join()`

Also printing the data of value 20 is lucky, because your program is not thread safe. In your example, you should use at least volatile keyword before value.

```
volatile int value = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass in the same `Runnable` object for all threads so the variable `value` is shared. The value you see depends on the sequence the threads are executed. If the main thread (the one creating the other threads) finishes first you will see this result.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating threads, you are passing them the same `Runnable`, that is, `t`. So all threads effectively work with the same `value`.

`Thread.start()` does not guarantee any particular ordering. The thread can start a little sooner or a little later. By the time thread gets a chance to run, your main thread might have already set the `value` to 20.

As a side note: you are using a shared variable without any synchronization. You should use a `volatile` or a `synchronized` to get predictable results.